# show json array inside of a json object using gorm

Tags: json, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to use gorm for my queries. I have a model called users just like this:

```
type Users struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID          uint   `gorm:"autoIncrement;unique" json:"id"`
    PhoneNumber string `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"phone_number"`
    Name        string `gorm:"default:dear user" json:"name"`
    Rank        uint   `json:"rank"`
    Score       uint   `json:"score"`
    Image       string `json:"image"`
    Email       string `json:"email"`
    Address     string `json:"address"`
    Birthday    string `json:"birthday"`
    Biography   string `json:"biography"`
}
```

and another model which represents the courses that the user has purchased.

```
type UserCourse struct {
    CourseID        uint   `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"course_id"`
    UserPhoneNumber string `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"user_phone_number"`
    Progress        uint   `json:"progress"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time
    UpdatedAt       time.Time
}
```

now I am looking for a way to return top 100 users based on their score with the courses they have purchased. in the other word, the below JSON object is desirable:

```
{
  "users":[
      {
        "id":1,
        "phoneNumber":"99999999",
        "name":"test",
        "rank":1,
        "score":123456789,
        "image":"http://...",
       "email":"test@test.com",
        "address":"test",
        "birthday":"2021-01-01",
        "biography":"test here",
        "courses": [
          {
                "course_id":1,
                "user_phone_number":"99999999",
                "progress": 53,
                "created_at": "2021-01-01",
                "updated_at": "2021-01-01",
          } ,
          {
              "course_id":2,
                "user_phone_number":"99999999",
                "progress":100,
                "created_at":"2021-02-01",
                "updated_at":"2021-03-01",
          }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

I know I have to use the below query to get top 100 users:

```
database.myDatabase.Order("rank asc").Limit(100).Find(users)
```

but unfortunately, I have no idea how to write the gorm suitable for the mentioned output.

Comment: Is `UserCourse` is a column in `Users` or is that a separate table and foreign key relationship? What would be your normal SQL query to figure out 100 top users? Can you also add your database schema?

Comment: @ShaileshSuryawanshi thanks for your attention. yes, the UserCourse is quite another table that contains the courses that each user has. the normal SQL for getting top users is simple: `select  * from users order by rank asc limit 100`

Comment: I believe that there is one to many relationship between user and Usercourses. To fetch the results `user with UserCourses` you might have needed to write a complex SQL query/join? I do not see foreign key constraint in `User` model for `UserCourse` thus the question. To get your expected response of Json you might need to Marshal the struct from database, thus the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend your `Users` model as such:

```
type Users struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID          uint   `gorm:"autoIncrement;unique" json:"id"`
    PhoneNumber string `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"phone_number"`
    Name        string `gorm:"default:dear user" json:"name"`
    Rank        uint   `json:"rank"`
    Score       uint   `json:"score"`
    Image       string `json:"image"`
    Email       string `json:"email"`
    Address     string `json:"address"`
    Birthday    string `json:"birthday"`
    Biography   string `json:"biography"`
    Courses     []*UserCourse `gorm:"foreignKey:UserPhoneNumber;references:PhoneNumber" json:"courses"`
}
```

you can then preload the courses into the user struct by using:

```
database.myDatabase.Preload("Courses").Order("rank asc").Limit(100).Find(users)
```